# Custom ProgressDialog extends Dialog or ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am simply trying to create a spinning progress dialog.  No text, no borders, no background.  Just a spinning notification that lightly is center on the screen on top of content.

I have seen two different Stack Overflow questions in creating this custom Dialog.

They both use this styling:

```
   <style name="NewDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:width">600dip</item>
    <item name="android:height">100dip</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>

</style>
```

But in the Java side, one extends Dialog and contains lots of custom content, the other one is simply this:

```
public class MyProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {

    public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.NewDialog);

    }

}
```

On the first (extends Dialog), I get a blank.  No dialog.  Nothing.  On the code sample just above, I get a shrunken small dialog spinning inside a black box that is off centered.

Which method is more correct and can I have a sample on how to implement this?

Also, how can I make that dialog transparent/borderless?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 'right way' to do this now would be to extend DialogFragment http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

If you are not using the compatibility library, you are not programming in the current Android world.

If you want to extend Dialog, then I have some example code here: https://github.com/tom-dignan/nifty/tree/master/src/com/tomdignan/nifty/dialogs In this code, I implemented a kind of 'progress dialog' by extending Dialog. I extended Dialog because I wanted full control and wanted my Dialog to be full-screen.

I would recommend reading the above DialogFragment doc and using that, though.

So really, there is no right or wrong way here. Extending any of the three classes will work, but the cleanest and most current would be the DialogFragment approach.

Comment: I am using this library actually.  I will give this a try and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Also, will extending DialogFragment assist in the custom look I am creating?  Transparent/borderless?

Comment: You will have complete control over that with styles and themes: DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME etc. You have complete control over the view you create in onCreateView. TIP: If making something 'transparent' for portability, use #00000100

Answer (score 5):

One way of doing it is to use a custom dialog, request feature No_Title and set the background drawable resource to transparent.

You can use the following code, I just wrote and tested it out on Android 4.0.3 ICS.

The xml layout in layout folder is, say dialog_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/dialogProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The java code to display the dialog and make it transparent is as follows.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog (this);

dialog.requestWindowFeature (Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView (R.layout.dialog_progress);
dialog.getWindow ().setBackgroundDrawableResource (android.R.color.transparent);
dialog.show ();
```

Answer (score 2):

Something similar can be achieved very easily by using frame-by-frame animation on an ImageView instead of making custom progress dialog. For this you just need a sequence of images(can be extracted from any gif). And then you can apply frame-by-frame animation on it. It will do exactly what you want.

I have done something similar with the code below -:

// XML for frame by frame animation

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/frame00"
    android:duration="150"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/frame01"
    android:duration="150"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/frame02"
    android:duration="150"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/frame03"
    android:duration="150"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/frame04"
    android:duration="150"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/frame05"
    android:duration="150"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/frame06"
    android:duration="150"/>
```

Java code for starting animation :-

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.progressDialog);
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.progress_dialog_icon_drawable_animation);
AnimationDrawable aniFrame = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
aniFrame = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
aniFrame.start();
```

[image: I achieved this from the above code]

Hope it helps !